# Sublime as external editor, error on Arduino compile dropdown: "avr-g++ is not recognized...", from Stino

Tags: arduino-ide

The error message, generated from Sublime, in its entirety...

Compiling KCT_Swimv4l...

Creating C:\Users\ken\Documents\Arduino_Build\KCT_Swimv4l\KCT_Swimv4l.ino.cpp.o...

'"avr-g++"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Stino - Error 1]

---

This is initial install of "Arduino-like IDE".

I used the following installation procedure:

- Install Sublime Text 3
- From Sublime, View --> Show Console
- From a web browser, open  https://sublime.wbond.net/installation and choose Sublime Text 3 version.
- Copy the code there to the Sublime-Console and press enter.
- From Sublime, CTRL + Shift + P --> Type "Install" and choose "Install package"
- Enter "Arduino" and choose "Arduino-like IDE"
- from Arduino --> Preferences --> Select Arduino Application Folder.

Same problem with any sketch.

System Configuration:

-Windows 10 x64, current level
-Sublime Text 3 x64, build 3126
-Arduino IDE 1.8.0

github info on Stino was not helpful.
Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution for it?
If not, I can open an issue there.

---

I have now done the following:
Uninstalled Sublime
Searched System drive and removed any remaining Sublime content
Searched System drive and removed any Stino content
Download WinAVR from http://winavr.sourceforge.net/download.html, selecting PATH option
Reinstalled Sublime Text 3 x64
Close & Reopen Sublime
From Sublime, View --> Show Console
From web browser, open https://sublime.wbond.net/installation and choose Sublime Text 3 version.
Copy the code there to the Sublime-Console and press enter
Close & Reopen Sublime
From Sublime, CTRL + Shift + P --> Type "Install" and choose "Install package"
Enter "Arduino" and choose "Arduino-like IDE"
Close & Reopen Sublime
From Arduino --> Preferences --> Select Arduino Application Folder

On Compile, error msg is now different:
  Compiling KCT_Swimv4l...
  Creating C:\Users\kct\Documents\Arduino_Build\KCT_Swimv4l\KCT_Swimv4l.ino.cpp.o...
  cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11"
  cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-flto"
  [Stino - Error 1]

Comment: *unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11"* - sounds like the compiler you installed is too old. It looks like it is from 2010. Right now it is 2017.

Comment: @Nick Gammon This was recommendation from answer posted.
Yes, this winavr copy is from 2010, as specified in answer, and the current year is now 2017.  I wondered about that.    

Now that I have a starting point, I now see that there is a newer copy at https://sourceforge.net/projects/winavr/, and I will try that out.

Comment: @Nick_Gammon  Nope, same copy.  Perhaps you can suggest a direction to pursue.

Comment: The avr-g++ that ships with the Arduino IDE would be more recent. For example with IDE 1.6.9 I find: `avr-g++.exe (GCC) 4.8.1`. That accepts `-std=gnu++11` on the command-line.

Comment: I found a whole lot of binaries (.exe files) in `arduino-1.6.9\hardware\tools\avr\bin` where `arduino-1.6.9` is my install folder.

Answer (score 1):

Download WinAVR from http://winavr.sourceforge.net/download.html, install it, add(in my case, its: C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin) to PATH variable of your system(If it was left unchecked while installing), And then try to build. I hope your problem will be solved.

**Update**

I have installed the latest version and found no board selection option. If you want to use it, you can download an older version. from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4zy7eqONHnuajk2aXlzOTJtaDQ/view it works on older version of arduino(probably 1.5 series)

Comment: I have updated problem description to show last actions taken in response to suggestion.  
Now get different error msgs.